# Error during installation of phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Installing phpmyadmin gives an error on MySQL.  I clicked on ignore after the retry option.  Now, phpmyadmin gives the following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: please help onthis

Comment: Please edit your question to explain exactly the steps you take to reach the error. It is not clear from your description what you are trying to accomplish or how.